# Por que preciso usar um application server com o Django?

Tags: python, django

Por que é necessário e qual a vantagem de se usar um application server, como por exemplo o Gunicorn, em um ambiente de produção?

Seria possível usar apenas o Django conversando diretamente com o servidor, como o Nginx?

Comment: Um empurrão para quem quiser escrever uma boa resposta: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/#original-rationale-and-goals-from-pep-333

Comment: olha não sou profundo conhecedor de **Django** só fiz cursos mas, durante o curso o Django foi apresentando como uma ferramenta de dev não para ir live, da mesma que forma que acontece com o **XAMPP** ou o **IIS Express** por exemplo, que são ferramentas para o ambiente de desenvolvimento/testes, por isso em live se usa por exemplo o **Nginx**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Além do que o Kauã respondeu, um programa com o uwsgi ou o Gunicorn tem outras tarefas.
A primeira função deles é se comunicar com o servidor web, usando o protocolo wsgi, como já explicado.

O servidor web não tem como executar Python diretamente. Antigamente, quando um servidor web precisava executar um script, usava-se o Common Gateway Interface (CGI). Com CGI, o servidor passava a requisição usando variáveis de ambiente e o script gerava a resposta escrevendo no console. Isso funcionou relativamente bem nos primórdios da web, mas chamar um script pelo servidor web não era rápido, prático ou seguro.

No Apache, que suporta módulos, resolveu-se criar o mod_python que plugava o interpretador no servidor web, seguindo o modelo do mod_perl e do mod_php. Este acoplamento resolveu vários problemas, mas o mod_python rodava no mesmo processo do servidor web, embora mais rápida a execução, gerou vários problemas e essas soluções foram caindo em desuso.

Então alguém teve a ideia de criar um servidor que seria responsável por rodar os scripts. Surgiram vários protocolos, entre eles o WSGI (Web Server Gateway Interface) e o FastCGI (Fast Gateway Interface, muito usado com PHP até hoje). Estes protocolos funcionam como elo entre o script (programa) e o servidor web. A vantagem é que hoje você pode desenvolver um script que usa o protocolo WSGI e plugá-lo no nginx ou no apache ou qualquer outro servidor que suporte WSGI.

Outas vantagens do protocolo WSGI (usado pelo Gunicorn):

- Pode reiniciar o script caso este caia
- Mantem o programa na memória entre requisições, diminuindo o tempo de inicialização
- Pode iniciar múltiplas cópias dos scripts para atender a várias requisições simultaneamente.
- Suporta vários tipos de script e não apenas uma só linguagem
- Pode se comunicar com os scripts usando protocolos de rede mais eficientes, como unix sockets
- Otimiza a comunicação usando um protocolo binário (mais compacto)

Do lado de quem desenvolve o script, a vantagem é poder contar com tudo isso e desenvolver código para um protocolo comum, independente do servidor web. É um ganha-ganha.

É muito comum rodar o Django com nginx e gunicorn com vários processos rodando django. Lembrando que no caso do Python, poder rodar em múltiplos processos ajuda bastante a não ter problemas de concorrência.
Com o Gunicorn você pode também ter várias máquinas rodando o Django (múltiplas cópias em cada uma), atrás de um só servidor web (dependendo da carga do sistema).

Por que você precisa de um servidor de aplicação? Porque o Django não foi otimizado para ser um servidor web. Ele não é capaz de responder a múltiplas conexões ou escalar como um servidor web (ngnix, apache). Um servidor web simples é incluido no Django, mas é usado apenas para desenvolvimento e em ambientes controlados, nunca em produção.

Versões mais modernas do uwsgi e guinicorn podem também atuar como servidores web, eu prefiro ter um programa especializado em cada tarefa que usar um substituto, mas tudo depende da configuração e carga do sistema. Um servidor como o ngnix para arquivos estáticos é imbatível, além de oferecer serviços como redirecionamento, reescrita de rotas, compactação, filtros, etc.

Comment: vale detalhar que o nginx e apache, quando falam com o servidor de aplicação conversam "HTTP" - WSGI e  ASGI são os protocolos "in process" que esses servidores usam como interface para rodar o código da aplicação em si. Ou seja: o nginxæpache/IIS só fazem o "forward" do HTTP (depois de filtro, validação, load-balancing, servir conteúdo estático) para os servidores de aplicação - que são servidores HTTP por natureza.

Answer (score 4):

Olá, Thiago! Para responder as suas perguntas é necessário voltar um pouquinho na história do Python.

Bom, vamos lá.

**Um servidor web tradicional não entende ou não consegue executar aplicativos Python**, então foi criado alguns módulos para esses web servers (como o mod_python do Apache) para que eles conseguissem executar essas aplicações. No entanto, esses módulos não era uma coisa padronizada, era apenas uma implementação que permitia que comandos em Python rodasse em um servidor, e eram bastante limitados e tinham muitas vulnerabilidades de segurança.

A comunidade reconheceu que era necessário bolar uma maneira segura e consistente para contornar esses problemas de interpretação dos *web servers*, então criaram a especificação WSGI, que de maneira bem simplificada, é uma interface padrão e sólida para a execução de código Python - se você quiser entrar em detalhes e entender o funcionamento, recomendo dar uma olhada na [documentação](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/#original-rationale-and-goals-from-pep-333).

Voltando para a sua pergunta, é recomendado ter um WSGI Server (como o Gunicorn) para que possa acontecer essa execução do Python adequadamente. As principais vantagens de utilizá-los em um ambiente de produção são:

1. Evita processamentos desnecessários;
2. Aumenta consideravelmente a velocidade de resposta;
3. Protege a sua aplicação.

E não achei nada que possa fazer o Django conversar diretamente com o Nginx. Talvez essa conexão direta seja impossível.

[Refêrencias](https://www.fullstackpython.com/wsgi-servers.html)

Comment: O NGINX "fala" http - é assim que ele se comunica cm o gunicorn e outros - o servidor de demonstração do django também é HTTP - é só colocar na configuração do NGINX que ele conectaria direto no django. vale como laboratório e aprendizado - mas o próprio django e outros framworks smpre alertam que esses servidores de desenvolvimento **não devem** ser usados em prod.